# How to mock FileList in $("fileupload").files[0]?

Tags: mocking, sinon-chai

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NlXJE.png)I am not able to make a mock for file upload using J query.

```js
 $('#fileUpload')[0].files[0]=  "mock image data here"
 $ ('#fileUpload').trigger ('change');
```

Please ref attachment .[[Actual FileList object]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPnmH.png)